# How to prevent MapKit from initially zooming when it is opened?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit

I have a map view of some locations I am getting from the previous segue's prepare function. I have a for in loop in view did load so that I can make annotations and display them. This all is working fine but when I click the show Map button in the previous view controller it takes me to my map view, and the mapView automatically zooms in a lot onto the first annotation. This could be a problem, because I want the user to see all of the locations.

My question is, how do I stop this initial zoom in the map from occuring?

Below is my viewDidLoad code.

By the way, bins is my entity in core data, and mapView is my IBOutlet variable connected to the Map Kit in storyboard.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        for bin in bins {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(bin.address ?? "", completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }

    
            if let placemarks = placemarks {
                // Get the first placemark
                let placemark = placemarks[0]

                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = bin.type

                if let location = placemark.location {
                    annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                    // Display the annotation
                    self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                    self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
                
                }
            }
            
        }
    )}
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:
`self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)`
zooms the map to show a single annotation, not all of your annotations. You need to create an array that contains all of your annotations and show that once you have created them all.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks. I was just wondering, if I put animated to false, would it still zoom?

Comment: Yes, the `animated` parameter (true/false) just controls whether the zoom is instantaneous or a smoothly animated transition, not whether or not it happens or not.